# Affect the order of initialization in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static, initialization

While reading book "**Thinking in Java**", I found this line

> C++, for example, has *problems* if one static expects another static to
>   be valid before the second one has been initialized

Subsequently I tried to ascertain myself with below [code](https://onlinegdb.com/BkEHUGe1m):

```
class A{
    public:
        static int x;
};
int A::x = B::y; //error 'B' has not been declared
class B{
    public:
        static int y;
};
int B::y = 10;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

My question is that is there a way to overcome this issue. Java handles this issue by loading the class code when a static field/method is accessed. How do we do it in C++?

Comment: You are mixing terms here. The book speaks of the static initialization order fiasco (which results in undefined behavior at runtime). Your verification deals with declaration order in a single file, and is not related to the SIFO.

Comment: Ok. got your point. Still curious to know about the workaround for the above code. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the initialization of `A::x` after the definition of `B`, which has to be complete type for the usage of `B::y`; and after the initialization of `B::y`, because `A::x` is initialized from it.

e.g.

```
class B{
    public:
        static int y;
};
int B::y = 10;

class A{
    public:
        static int x;
};
int A::x = B::y;
```

The [initialization order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Dynamic_initialization) is specified as follow:

> Ordered dynamic initialization, which applies to all other non-local variables: within a single translation unit, initialization of these variables is always sequenced in exact order their definitions appear in the source code. Initialization of static variables in different translation units is indeterminately sequenced. Initialization of thread-local variables in different translation units is unsequenced.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you have to initialize your static member variables and in the correct order.

If they are const, you can directly initialize them in the class.